# javax.servlet.ServletException: missing jspFile

Tags: java, tomcat

I use tomcat 7.0.29 and when I deploy my app(an applet) and start the tomcat from eclipse, I got this error.

SEVERE: Servlet /test threw load() exception `javax.servlet.ServletException`: missing jsp File

What could be the problem?

Comment: Do you really have an applet? Or a webapp? Or both?

Comment: Please write complete directory structure of your webapp and also web.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia told me

> Java applets can run in a Web browser using a Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM), or in [Sun's AppletViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppletViewer), a stand-alone tool for testing
>   applets

And for this:

> SEVERE: Servlet /test threw load() exception
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: missing jspFile

Did Your Applet really Contain JSP files? If So then You can Run it on `TOMCAT`

To run an `Java Applet` embed `<applet>` tag as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
  "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>HelloWorld_example.html</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>A Java applet example</H1>
<P>Here it is: <APPLET code="HelloWorld.class" WIDTH="200" HEIGHT="40">
This is where HelloWorld.class runs.</APPLET></P>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Or You can Use appletviewer as shown [here](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/JavaInDOS.html)

Comment: wikipedia is not suggested for citation of technical details. Use Java Doc instead to cite the content.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I found that there was a mention of a JSP file in my web.xml. I placed this JSP file in some other directory but forgot to update the path in web.xml. As soon as I updated the path in web.xml. The error was resolved.

```
   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TH</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/Representation/th.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>TH</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/th.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```